# Missing gmail notifiation when turning phone on?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I was playing with using gmails snooze function for reminders. I tagged certain messages and only allow notifications for these messages. This seemed to be working well. But this morning my phone had run out of charge, I switched it on and I appeared to receive no notifications for the unsnoozed emails when my phone was off.

This is annoying, I want reliable notifications that I don't miss. Does gmail not send notificatios when it starts and is there a way to make it do so?

Comment: AFAIK, Gmail only shows notifications when the app syncs in the background and there are unread emails. I'm unsure if there's a way to force automatic background sync on startup.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks... I guess I'm happy as long as the sync happens *evetually* for my phone. I tested it with unsnoozing messages when my phonen was on.